# Javascript Memoization Explanation?

Tags: javascript

Reading an example from a book, can someone explain how the function call to fibonacci takes in the argument 'i' when the function itself doesn't declare any parameters?

```
var fibonacci = (function () {
    var memo = [0, 1];
    var fib = function (n) {
        var result = memo[n];
        if (typeof result !== 'number') {
            result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
            memo[n] = result;
        }
        return result;
    };
    return fib;
}());

for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
    document.writeln('// ' + i + ': ' + fibonacci(i));
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are creating a self-executing anonymous function `(function(){}());` which inside it returns the `fib` function, which takes an argument. `var fib = function(n){}` ... `return fib;`

```
var fibonacci = (function () { // Self-executing anonymous function
    var memo = [0, 1];         // local variable within anonymous function
    var fib = function (n) {   // actual fib function (takes one argument)
        var result = memo[n];
        if (typeof result !== 'number') {
            result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
            memo[n] = result;
        }
        return result;
    };
    return fib; // return fib (fibonacci is now set to the function fib defined above, which takes one argument)
}());
```

This system (returning a function from a self-executing anonymous function) allows for you to define variable in a local scope that can still be used by the returned function, but not by functions outside the scope. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/32yj4/).

*This technique is called `closure` in JavaScript. Read more about it on the  [MDN guide.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)*

Comment: It's worth noting that the technique of the inner function accessing the variables on the outter function even after the outter function has returned, is known as `closure`

Comment: This is from the book Javascript - The good parts and there is a better description of the process there.

Answer (score 6):

Because the function *returns* a function that *does* take a parameter.

Answer (score 6):

To understand this, I think it is helpful to work with a simpler example. Take a look at the two memoized functions below. The only difference is the `()` after `add : function (){ ... }()` on the successful memorization code.

```
    var failed_memoization = {
        add : function (){
            var counter;
            return function(number){
                if(counter){
                    counter = counter + number;
                    return counter;
                }
                counter = number;
                return counter;
            } //NOTE: NO function call brackets here
        }
    }

    var successful_memoization = {
        add : function (){
            var counter;
            return function(number){
                if(counter){
                    counter = counter + number;
                    return counter;
                }
                counter = number;
                return counter;
            }
        }()  //NOTE: the function call brackets here!!
    };
}
```

Now let's execute these two functions.

```
console.log('Failed Memoization');
console.log(failed_memoization.add(5));      //We wanted 5, but this prints the text of the function instead.... Okay, lets try something else
console.log(failed_memoization.add()(5));    //5
console.log(failed_memoization.add()(10));   //10 (Wanted it to be 5+10 = 15.
console.log('successful_memoization');
console.log(successful_memoization.add(8));  //8
console.log(successful_memoization.add(16)); //24 (This is what we wanted 8 + 16 = 24)
```

So what's going on here is that for `successful_memoization` when we put `()` to the end of its `add : function(){...}()`. As such, this function is executed immediately on the creation of the static object. In turn, executing that function returns the object `function (number){...}` wich results in the assignment: `add : function (number){...}` **NOT** `add : function(){}` as it initially appears.

What is also important to note is that `var counter` is declared **outside** `return function(name){}`. As it is still being used within `add : function(number){...}`, this variable is accessible within that function. For `failed_memoization.add()(number)`, it uses a new `counter` each time we execute that function, because we execute the first function, and then the inner function on each call. For `successful_memoization.add(number)` we executed the outer function upon initialization, and so `counter` will persist through all subsequent calls and will not be overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

There is a self-calling function that returns the function with the identifier `fib` which is then assigned to the identifier `fibonacci`. This way you can create a private variable `memo` which is only accessible by the function. So `var fibonacci` in fact is `function(n){...}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var fibonacci = (function() {
    ...
    return fib;
})();
```

This is a self-executing function.

It declares a function expression which returns a function (`fib`), executes the outer function expression immediately (`()`), and assigns its return value (which is `fib`) to the `fibonacci` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Function `fibonacci` does take one argument. Note that the unnamed function that starts on the first line is not the function that ends up being known as `fibonacci`. That unnamed function is immediately called since you have `()` immediately after closing brace `}`. This unnamed function returns `fib`, a local variable to which a single-argument function is assigned. Thus, `fibonacci` ends up referring to the function returned by the unnamed function, i.e. `fibonacci` is this:

```
var fib = function (n) {
    var result = memo[n];
    if (typeof result !== 'number') {
        result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        memo[n] = result;
    }
    return result;
};
```

Note that this function refers to local variables of the unnamed function for the purpose of memoizing.

The critical thing to notice was `()` which calls the unnamed function immediately, here are some examples that illustrate this technique:

```
var a = (function() { return 1; });
```

Variable `a` holds a function which returns 1.

```
var a = (function() { return 1; }());
```

Here however, variable `a` holds value 1.