# Svelte recomputes too much on change

Tags: svelte, each

I'm implementing an app where the user should be able to place things on a 2D grid by clicking on it, and also be able to drag the grid around. I have a functional prototype here:

https://svelte.dev/repl/ebfde34fafda4b79859f70dd8f984b12?version=3.54.0

```html
<script>
    
    let project = {
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        circles: [{
            id: 1,
            x: 50,
            y: 50,
        }]
    }
    let dragInfo = null
    
    function onBackgroundDragStart(event){
        
        dragInfo = {
            action: "moveBackground",
            dragStartProjectOffsetX: project.offsetX,
            dragStartProjectOffsetY: project.offsetY,
            startMouseX: event.clientX,
            startMouseY: event.clientY
        }
        
        const dragImage = document.createElement("img")
        dragImage.style.display = "none"
        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragImage, 0, 0)
        
    }
    
    function onBackgroundDragOver(event){
        
        switch(dragInfo.action){
            
            case "moveBackground":
                
                const dragDistanceX = event.clientX - dragInfo.startMouseX
                const dragDistanceY = event.clientY - dragInfo.startMouseY
                
                project.offsetX = dragInfo.dragStartProjectOffsetX + dragDistanceX
                project.offsetY = dragInfo.dragStartProjectOffsetY + dragDistanceY
                
            break
            
        }
        
    }
    
    // Create new circle on click.
    function onClick(event){
        
        project.circles.push({
            id: project.circles.length + 1,
            x: event.clientX - project.offsetX,
            y: event.clientY - project.offsetY,
        })
        
        project.circles = project.circles
        
    }
    
    function getText(circle){
        console.log("getText() is called.")
        return circle.x.toString()[0]
    }
    
</script>

<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-click-events-have-key-events -->
<div
    class="app"
    
    draggable="true"
    on:dragstart={onBackgroundDragStart}
    on:dragover|preventDefault={onBackgroundDragOver}
    
    on:click={onClick}
    
    style:background-position-x={`${project.offsetX}px`}
    style:background-position-y={`${project.offsetY}px`}
>
    
    {#each project.circles as circle (circle.id)}
        <div
            class="circle"
            style:transform={`translate(${
                project.offsetX + circle.x
            }px, ${
                project.offsetY + circle.y
            }px) translate(-50%, -50%)`}
        >
            {getText(circle)}
        </div>
    {/each}
    
</div>

<style>

.app{
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vw;
    background-color: silver;
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) .1em, transparent .1em), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) .1em, transparent .1em);
    background-size: 2em 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circle{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
```

The prototype works as expected, but Svelte recomputes too much on changes:

1. When dragging the background, only `project.offsetX` and `project.offsetY` are updated, but in `{#each project.circles ...}`, `getText(circle)` is called again for each circle, even though it just makes use of the `circle.x` and will never change when `project.offsetX` and `project.offsetY`
2. Same when adding a circle (`getText(circle)` is called for each circle again)

This is very problematic in my case, because `getText()` is in my true case another function that is very expensive to call, so it's important it's not being called unnecessary many times (it starts to lag).

I know I can get around (1) in the list above by putting the `circles` array in it's own variable, but that is not really a good solution, since I need to store all information about the project in one and the same object (so I later conveniently can save it in a JSON file), so I would prefer to not use that. And the problem with (2) still exists.

How can I get Svelte to not update unnecessarily much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think the problem lies with how Svelte re-renders/updates. When you modify a component, for instance in your case when you drag the grid, it is normal for Svelte to re-render the circles in order to properly repaint them in your browser. The same applies when you update your list of circles (although I am a bit surprised *all* circles are re-rendered when you simply add a circle considering you properly add a `(circle.id)` key to your `#each` loop?).

The solution to your expensive computation issue is to use *[memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103739/javascript-memoization)* in order to cache expensive computation results, thus making subsequent function calls with identical inputs virtually free of computation cost. The exact implementation is really up to you, though you will want your expensive computation function to be *pure* (i.e. no side-effects, and you always get the same output from given inputs) for memoization to function properly.

Once you have memoization in place, expensive computation should not be an issue anymore, and neither will be Svelte's re-rendering.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct, but I now realize that I have simplified my question a bit too much to be applicable to my true case. In my true case, I don't call `getText(circle)` in `{#each}...{/each}`, but instead passes the `circle` object to a Svelte component, and that Svelte component then in turn renders a web component that is quite expensive to render, and when dragging the 2D grid around, all gets re-rendered and lags, when all that needs to change is changing the position. But I guess splitting the `project` object into smaller pieces is the way to go.

Comment: I am obviously not familiar with the details of your project, but another possibility could perhaps lay in the use of a more dedicated/optimized tool for your graphics rendering & manipulation. Using SVGs (and the D3 library) over standard elements might really help if your app is graphic-intensive.