# JavaScript write a function which caches a function(memoization)

Tags: javascript

I have been asked this question and I wasn't sure how I can target this.

**Question:**

> Write a cache function which caches a function and returns a result if
>   it was already executed in the past.

```
Let's say if there's a function Fibonacci(20) = 6765

cacheFunction(Fibonacci(20)) // it should not execute the function instead return 6765. 

But if i give cacheFunction(Fibonacci(21)) //It's not cached, execute the function
```

**My attempt:**

```
function cacheFunction(funct) {

    var obj = {};

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(funct)) { //checking if the argument is in the object?
        return obj[funct];
    } else { //if not present, then execute the function, store it in cache and return the value.
        obj[funct];
        return funct;
    }
}
```

**But I'm not able to understand how to get the *arguments* in one function inside another function? (The person told me that I need to use closure to get it)**

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: BTW: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+memoize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Memoization Explanation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548802/javascript-memoization-explanation)

Answer (score 1):

It's not `cacheFunction(Fibonacci(20))`, it's `cacheFunction(Fibonacci)(20)`. You indeed cannot get the parameters of `Fibonacci`, you cannot alter that function to somehow access them. What `cacheFunction` is supposed to do is to construct a *new function* that provides the same functionality as the passed-in `funct` (i.e. `Fibonacci` in your case) by wrapping around it. In the wrapper function that will eventually get called with the input (e.g. `20`) you can access the arguments and check the cache for their values, and potentially pass them on to `funct`.

Answer (score -2):

Memoization/caching technique is available as part of underscore.js. You can directly use it if needed. I also added a sitepoint article which walks you through implementing memoization in JS.

[Implementing Memoization in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-memoization-in-javascript/)

[memoize in underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#memoize)