# Random Fibonacci Generator

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I'm trying to create a simple program in javascript where the Fibonacci square can be created by a random number sequence but I can't seem to connect both parts of my code. The first side being: the call for a random number and the second part: calculating the Fibonacci square.

```
var n = function getRandomNum() {
     return Math.floor(Math.random()*100) +1;
  }



function fib(x) {
  if (x < 2) {
    return x;
  } else {
    return fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2);
  }
}
 console.log(fib(n));
```

Tell me where I'm going wrong. These are the errors I get when I run it.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at fib:7:13
    at fib:11:12
    at fib:11:12
    at fib:11:12
    at fib:11:12
    at fib:11:12
```

Comment: you assign the function `getRandomNum` to `n` and not the return value of calling that function. Write `function getRandomNum() { ... }, var n = getRandomNum();`

Comment: `n` is a function - you're not calling `n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from not invoking the random number generator, you're using a very poorly optimized algorithm. If you think through all the redundant calls that need to take place, you'll see why the stack limit is reached.

```js
var n = function getRandomNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}(); // <-- quick inline invocation... not normally how you'd use this.

console.log(n);

function fib(x) {
  function _fib(x, a, b) {
    if (x < 2) {
      return a;
    }
    return _fib(x - 1, b, a + b);
  }

  return _fib(x, 0, 1);
}
console.log(fib(n));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't call `n` function, you should call it like the following.

```
var n = function getRandomNum() {
     return Math.floor(Math.random()*100) +1;
  }



function fib(x) {
  if (x < 2) {
    return x;
  } else {
    return fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2);
  }
}
 console.log(fib(n));
```

But, there's a huge problem in your code, as *@rock star* mentioned, there's no any optimizing process in your code. That is why your code has caused **the problem on memory leak**

To avoid this, you can simply use *memoization*, click this link you don't have any clue on it.
[Javascript Memoization Explanation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548802/javascript-memoization-explanation)

So, your code can be improved like the folloiwng, by adapting memoization algorithm.

```js
var n = function getRandomNum() {
     return Math.floor(Math.random()*100) +1;
  }

var result = [];
result[0] = 1;
result[1] = 1;

function fib(x) {
  var ix, ixLen;
  for(ix = 0, ixLen = x; ix < ixLen; ix++){
    if(!result[ix]){
      result[ix] = result[ix-2] + result[ix-1];
    }
  }
  console.log('n:', x, ' result: ', result[ix-1]);
  return result[ix-1];
}
console.log(fib(n()));
```

Compare the result with this site.
http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html

Comment: Thank you so much!