# How does the cache update in javascript memoized fibonacci recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Considering the following recursive Fibonacci function that’s been optimized using memoization.
No other code apart from this.

```
function memoizeFibonacci(index, cache = []) {
    if (cache[index]) {
        return cache[index]
    } else {
        if (index < 3) return 1
        else {
            cache[index] = memoizeFibonacci(index - 1, cache) + memoizeFibonacci(index - 2, cache)
        }
    }
    console.log(cache)
    return cache[index];
}
memoizeFibonacci(6)
```

Can someone please explain how is the cache array updated? When viewing the console logs the cache seems to hold all the previous values from the resolved recursive functions. But to me, this doesn't make sense as the cache is not stored outside memoizeFibonacci so the scope should not allow this.

Comment: The array is passed on each call of the method so it keeps adding to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with closures. This is simply passing the same array to nested recursive calls.

When you pass an array (or any object for that matter) to a function, the array is not copied, rather a reference to it is passed, so changing the array in the recursive call will affect the same array.

Here is an example of what is basically happening:

```js
function foo(arr) {
  arr[0] = "hello";
}

let arr = [];
foo(arr);

console.log(arr); // changed because of the call to foo
```

Notice that the recursive calls to `memoizeFibonacci` is explicitly passing the `cache` object as the second parameter, so each recursive call is sharing the same array as the top-level call, and any changes to the `cache` object in the recursive calls is reflected in the top-level call aswell.

BTW, this type of memoization is not persistent, meaning that these two calls:

```
memoizeFibonacci(6);
memoizeFibonacci(10);
```

don't share the same `cache` object. They each use a different `cache` array that must be reconstructed from scratch rather than the call to `memoizeFibonacci(10)` using the `cache` object already constructed in the call to `memoizeFibonacci(6)` and appending to it. A more efficient memoization makes use of closures like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548823/9867451

**Note:** If you are asking why all the `console.log(cache)` print out the same exact filled array, that's because they are printing the same array, and the values you see in the console are not necessarily added at the point of the `console.log`. Take a look at this other question: [array.length is zero, but the array has elements in it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42260524/9867451). To log exactly what's in the `cache` object at the time of the `console.log`, change it to:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(cache));
```

Comment: I knew it was a reference thing but just couldn't conceptualise it until I saw this simple snippet. I guess I got a bit of tunnel vision. Thanks.

Comment: @Mircea You're welcome! I edited the answer to add a few points, please take a look at them :)

Answer (score 1):

Every nested recursive function adds its item when it resolves only during the chain of executions of the recursion.

`console.log` is asynchronous and probably shows repeatedly the final result. There is no specification about how `console.log` work so it can act differently depending on the environment, it's I/O.

Even if you make it work as expected in your environment, it can work differently for other user. An hypothesis based on the use of `console` in your algorithm is not correct.

Kyle Simpson references:

- Recursion in JS https://github.com/getify/Functional-Light-JS/blob/master/manuscript/ch8.md
- Console log https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/async%20%26%20performance/ch1.md#async-console